# How to set log4net SmtpAppender sender name in .config file

Tags: c#, smtp, log4net

I tried to find a solution for this minor problem for quite a while but couldn't find an answer.

I want to set the sender's name of my e-mails that I send using log4net SmtpAppender, but I can't figure out how.

This is my log4net appender config:

```xml
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="sender@sending.com" />
  <from value="receiver@receiving.rom" />
  <subject value="test logging message" />
  <smtpHost value=" ... " />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <port value="587" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <username value=" ... " />
  <password value=" ... " />
  <EnableSsl value="true"/>
  <lossy value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="FATAL"/>
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

It works, but when I receive the e-mail, the **name** of the sender is whatever is in front of the @ in the "from" parameter, in this case "sender" (as it's sender@sending.com).

What I want is a custom name, let's say *Notifier*, but still keep sending from sender@sending.com

I tried different parameters (just random guesses, since I couldn't find any good ideas while searching the net)... like from_name or sender_name ... nothing works...

It's my first question on SO, hope I met all criteria and someone can help me :)

Cheers

Comment: The log4net documentation http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppenderMembers.html does not appear to have such a property for as far as I can see

Comment: Yes I noticed that too but I can hardly believe that it's not possible, as SMTP should allow to set that normally. Maybe log4net team just forgot about it, but ... hmm...

Comment: Where I work we use email addresses that are good enough as a name. For example here are a few of them: DatabaseSpaceAlert@xyz.com; ShippingManager@xyz.com.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, Eric...but unfortunately that doesn't move us closer to a solution at all :) it's not the end of the world though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SmtpAppender (Line 469)](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Appender/SmtpAppender.cs?view=markup) attaches a from address by using `new MailAddress(m_from)`, which accepts an email address. Fortunately, you can specify a name in the address field, stated under the Remarks section on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Email format:

```
Notifier <sender@sending.com>
```

Log4net XML configuration example:

```
<from value="Notifier &lt;sender@sending.com&gt;" />
```